# What technique is it called when a camera recognizes objects

Tags: camera, image-recognition

Im wondering what the technique is called when a camera can recognize objects such as a face, hand, glass etc. Ive search a little but its hard to search when you have no idea what you are looking for :S.

I dont know if this is the right site but it is a programming thing.

Answer (score 0):

Object Recognition, Computer vision, Image recognition, Vision recognition, etc.

Google 'Computer Vision' to get a bunch of related terms.

This question is a bit vague and perhaps unsuitable for this site, at leastt with the tags you have used, imho.
Please be more specific?